# sending an array with paypal return url

Tags: php, yii, paypal, urlencode

I am trying to send an array in the paypal return url as following:

```
$tempArr = serialize($rest_arg);
$query = urlencode($tempArr);
$data['currencyCodeType'] = "USD";
$data['paymentType'] = "Sale";
$data['returnURL'] = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)."/user/confirm?data=".$query."&plan_id=".$plan_id."&reactivate=0";
$data['cancelURL'] = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)."/user/cancel";
$data['paymentAmount'] = '0.00';
$data['paymentDesc'] = $plan_name;
```

But while paypal is returning to my return function, I am getting only the serialized array. Its not in url encoded format.

Comment: Is that space between "confirm?" and "data" needed?

Comment: no, it was just a typing error.